# Using vtkImageActor for adding mask to vtkImageViewer2

Tags: vtk

I am developing on an application based on VTK and GDCM for viewing medical (DICOM) images.

The application has three windows that respectively show XY, YZ and XZ orientations (axial, coronal and sagittal). This is similar to the 2D views [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InVesalius#/media/File:Invesalius3_promed0446.png). I use [vtkImageViewer2](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageViewer2.html) for this. The voxel values of the DICOM images are passed on to an instance of [vtkImageData](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageData.html). The instance of the vtkImageData is the passed on the to three instances of vtkImageViewer2 (let's use imageViewerXY, imageViewerYZ and imageViewerXZ). The orientation of each instance of vtkImageViewer2 is then set using `SetSliceOrientationToXY()`, `SetSliceOrientationToYZ()` and `SetSliceOrientationToXZ()`. Without the mask, I can see the slices, couple the windows and scroll through the images perfectly fine.

To add the mask so that it is shown in the three views, I use [vtkImageActor](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageActor.html). For the XY view, which is the default view, this works fine. I update the instance of vtkImageActor, which I call maskActorXY based on the mouse events of XY window as follows:

```
int extent[6];
imageViewerXY->GetImageActor->GetDisplayExtent(extent);
maskActorXY->SetDisplayExtent(extent);
maskActorXY->Update();
imageViewerXY->GetRenerer->Render();
```

Now, when I do the same for the other two windows so that I can see the 3D mask in the other two orientations, for example for the YZ orientation,

```
imageViewerYZ->GetImageActor->GetDisplayExtent(extent);
maskActorYZ->SetDisplayExtent(extent);
maskActorYZ->Update();
imageViewerYZ->GetRenerer->Render();
```

I get an error message that traces to vtkImageData and accessing pixel values outside of the extent set for the mask actor.

I have a limited familiarity with VTK, but looking at the [source code of vtkImageViewer2](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Interaction/Image/vtkImageViewer2.cxx) (see `UpdateDisplayExtent()` on line 341), I don't understand why pixel values out side of the specified display extent are requested from my instances of vtkImageActor that represent the mask.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Since I am not familiar with VTK, I may not be able to provide a clear explanation. All that I needed were the following two lines for each mask to force its mappers to face the camera:

```
maskActorYZ->GetMapper()->SetAtFocalPointOn();
maskActorYZ->GetMapper()->SliceFacesCameraOn();
```

(see `[vtkImageMapper3D][1]` class.)